# Sequelize eager load nested associations

Tags: javascript, node.js, sequelize.js

I'm fairly new to Sequelize, and I can't seem to find an answer to my question.

I have a model 'team' which has associations defined as:

```
    team.hasMany(members, {foreignKey: 'memberId', onDelete: 'cascade'});
    team.belongsTo(memberDetails, {as: 'type1', foreignKey: 'type1Id'});
    team.belongsTo(memberDetails, {as: 'type2', foreignKey: 'type2Id'});
```

I want to load team rows from the database, and as I load each row I want the (some of) the associations to be included as well.  I use the following code:

```
team.findAll({
   include: [
               {
                   model: memberDetails,
                   as: 'type1'
               }
            ]
})
```

This loads the teams as expected, and loads associated members, and also loads and attaches details for 'type1' members per the include.

However, the memberDetail model also has associations:

```
    memberDetails.belongsTo(memberInfo, {as: 'type1', foreignKey: 'type1Id'});
    memberDetails.belongsTo(memberInfo, {as: 'type2', foreignKey: 'type2Id'});
```

What I want is the memberInfo associations to be loaded for each member loaded - similar to the INCLUDEd memberDetails, but I don't know how to specify the INCLUDE for the eagerly loaded associations.

Can anyone help?

Answer (score 13):

You could do something like this, as explained in the [Sequelize Doc about nested eager loading](https://sequelize.org/master/manual/eager-loading.html#nested-eager-loading).

```
team.findAll({
  include: [{
    model: memberDetails,
    as: 'type1Details',
    include: [{
      model: memberInfo,
      as: 'type1Info'
    }]
  }]
});
```

Comment: Maybe my question isn't as clear as it could be.  Wouldn't this solution eagerly load 'type1Info' that belongsTo 'type1Details'?

My code gets the team rows, and for each team gets the associated member rows (via the hasMany association).  It also loads the 'memberDetails' for each team (via the existing include - 1 per team).

What I want is, for each member row, load the associated 'type1Info' for that row.  

My implementation of your solution you provided fails to compile with error:

SequelizeEagerLoadingError: memberDetails is not associated to memberInfo!

Possible my fault...

Comment: This solution should do exactly that. The findAll method retrieves all the teams. The include type1Details would load the memberDetails. Finally, the include type1Info would load the memberInfo of each memberDetail. Usually when I define the associations, their name is unique in the whole model. Could you try to change the as property in each belongsTo with an unique string, just like those I used in the includes?

Comment: Also, even if it could be a little too much, you can also load everything that is related to a particular team by using this options object `{ include: [{ all: true, nested: true }]}`

Comment: See how beautiful this is. Relations are much easier with Sequelize.